# angular required message on $error.required OR (pristine AND empty value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

I have searched for a solution all over, so here is my first question to this site:

I am trying to have some nice validation in angular (ionic) page where the logic is I want to show a "`Required`" message under label when either there is a validation error (`$error.required`) OR the field has not been touched and is empty (like a first time load).  I can use pristine to check if it is not been modified, but if the form loads values from the model subsequently (like when restoring from `localstorage`), it still shows the "`required`" validation message.

I have tried the following:

```html
<form name="wdform" novalidate>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
<span class="input-label green-small">ID</span>
<div class="validation" ng-show="wdform.userid.$error.required ||
(wdform.userid.$pristine && wdform.userid.length < 1)" >
  Required 
</div>
<input name="userid" ng-model="input.UserID" type="text" required>
</label> 
  ... rest of form...
</form>
```

Also have tried:

```html
<div class="validation" ng-show="wdform.userid.$error.required ||
(wdform.userid.$pristine && input.UserID.length < 1)" >
```

and various other permutations such as:

```
(wdform.userid.$pristine && input.UserID == '')

(wdform.userid.$pristine && wdform.userid.$invalid)

etc. ad nauseum.
```

On a separate but related note, I have also found that the built in validation is pretty brittle when it comes to form and field names... it only seems to work at all if the form name is only lowercase and/or contains no special characters ("`DumbForm`" and "`dumb-form`" fails, but "`smartform`" works).

Anyway, does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I feel like your two scenarios, (1) $error.required and (2) pristine and empty, might be redundant. Anytime #2 would be true, so would #1. I think you could use just #1. 

Look at this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PgQ3vEIOKkfA38dDWjhp?p=preview

However, I was a bit unsure under what circumstances you wanted the message to be shown, so this may not be correct. Can you elaborate on the exact behavior you are seeking?

Comment: @nfiniteloop - the behavior I am going for is: when the form first loads with empty fields, it should show the required message.  When the user types content into it, the required message should go away.  HOWEVER - I also want to NOT display the required message when the form loads with the data already populated and here is the issue.  What is happening is that if the page loads with the data already in the fields from the model, it STILL shows the required message and that is what I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your two scenarios, (1) $error.required and (2) pristine and empty, might be redundant. Anytime #2 would be true, so would #1. I think you could use just #1.

Look at this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PgQ3vEIOKkfA38dDWjhp?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="myController as vm">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <form name="wdform">
    <input type="text" name="userid" ng-model="userId" required/>
    <div ng-show="wdform.userid.$error.required">Required</div>
  </form>
</body>
```

However, it sounds like you are populating your form on page load some times from localStorage and somehow this is not causing the $error.required property to be changed to true, but it should. So your real problem I think lies in need to call $scope.$apply() or something to tell angular to run validations again.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was related to where the validation div was placed.

If the validation div was placed *before* the input field (so that it displayed the validation message beneath the field label), I encountered the error specified in this question.

By placing it *after* the input tag, it works as expected (with the validation message beneath the input field).

I would consider this a bug either in Angular or Ionic.  Hopefully it will be corrected in the upcoming version 2 of both.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="f3.form.reset()">
```

Just add the click in the button.so form loads values from the model in reset().Once click the button form will reset. You get new form with no errors.